# How to bind JDialog box and its corresponding JFrame (where the JDialog box was launched from)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jdialog

I am facing a weird issue while developing a java desktop application using Netbeans IDE.

The scenario is as following:
There is a JFrame. It has a button which will launch a JDialog box. As soon as JDialog box launches, JFrame will be disabled for editing. Now I have JFrame and JDialog box opened on my screen.
Just press Windows+D to go to desktop directly and then click on the icon of java application on the task bar. You can see that the JFrame will be shown now. You even won't be able to edit it because I have disabled it on opening of JDialog box. At this point, it looks like my application hanged and stopped working. Only after pressing Alt+Tab button, you will be able to figure out that there is some popup already opened corresponding to this screen.

Now my question: Is there any way to stick these two screens (JFrame+JDialog) together so that even after pressing Windows+D and then clicking on icon on taskbar, both the screen should open simultaneously.

Hope I am clear in explaining my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the JFrame to the JDialog constructor to set it as its parent.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//....
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
```

Edit: in a comment you mentioned Netbeans creates a subclass of JDialog. Add an argument with type Frame to the class extending JDialog, like so:

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog
{

    public MyDialog(Frame frame)
    {
        super(frame);
    }
}
```

Where you'd normally make an instance of MyDialog in your frame, you could now do the following:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);
//.... 
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Since I am using Netbeans IDE, for each screen, it creates a separate class with extending the class of screen type. In my case, it has created two classes which extends (JFrame & JDialog). How would I achieve this as you have suggested here?